# Java ArrayList only iterating through first 4 elements?

Tags: java, file, for-loop, arraylist, iteration

I'm new to Java and programming in general so excuse my ignorance.

I'm trying to iterate across two ArrayLists, scannedcriteria and scannedcandidates, such that each element in scannedcandidates will call each element in scannedcriteria with the method meetsCriteria.

For some reason, it's only iterating through the first 4 elements of scannedcriteria. When I added a for loop that printed each element in scannedcriteria before the main for loop, it printed them all. I tested it again with writing to the file, and again, it wrote them all. It gives the correct length of the arraylist at the beginning of the try block as well.

So the issue has to be in the syntax of the nested for loops. But I've also tried switching them out for whiles, enhanced for loops...nothing worked.

I feel so stupid and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

```
    void printResults(){
    try  {
        FileOutputStream bw = new FileOutputStream("results4.txt");
        for (ExamCriteria ex: scannedcriteria){             
            byte [] towrite = ex.getInfo().getBytes();
            bw.write(towrite);
            for (Candidate can: scannedcandidates){
                String result = can.meetsCriteria(checktime, ex);
                if (result != null){                    
                towrite = (", " + result).getBytes();
                bw.write(towrite);                  
            }
                if (scannedcandidates.indexOf(can) == (scannedcandidates.size() -1 )){                      
                    towrite = ( "\r\n").getBytes();
                    bw.write(towrite);
                }                               
        }               
    }           
    bw.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       
    }
```

Comment: The only logical explanation is an exception was thrown.

Comment: Maybe try using a debugger or printing some debug statements? The most obvious thing to expect is a null Candidate that causes an NPE to get swallowed...

Comment: Well, those catch blocks will only catch 2 specific types of Expressions.  You're likely throwing a different kind of exception (ahem... perhaps a NullPointerException), which must be swallowed by some code higher up the call stack. Try catching a generic Exception below your IOException.

Comment: You'll also get a NPE if `getInfo()` returns null for any of your ExamCriteria objects, which you did not mention testing in your question...

Comment: I added a Throwable exc catch block to catch any other sort of exception and nothing was thrown. And I did actually have a print statement right after the try block opened printing all the examcriteria objects getInfo(), and all of them (not just the first four) were printed.

Comment: I think I've discovered the problem though? I added a finally block with a print statement and that didn't print so I think the program isn't actually finishing

Comment: Sounds like there's an infinite loop in `Candidate.meetsCriteria()`.

Comment: Step through this with a debugger.  It's the best way.